# How do I copy input from Wolfram Mathematica and paste it into my browser's editor?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I want to copy the input from Mathematica, but when I'm doing that, I see here different input.
I mean how can I copy the input from Mathematica and  post here the exact input to ask you a question?
 I have copied a which is look like when I post here

```
DSolve[Subscript[\[Phi], 4]''[\[Tau]] + Subscript[\[Phi], 4][\[Tau]] +
    Subscript[\[Omega], 
    2] {- Subscript[p, 2] Cos[\[Tau]] - 
      Subscript[q, 2] Sin[\[Tau]] - (4 Subscript[g, 2])/
       6 Subscript[p, 1]^2 Cos[
        2 \[Tau]]} - {Subscript[\[CapitalDelta]p, 2] Cos[\[Tau]] + 
     Subscript[\[CapitalDelta]q, 2] Sin[\[Tau]] + 
     Subscript[g, 2]/3 {Cos[2 \[Tau]] - 3}} - 
   Subscript[\[Omega], 3 ] Subscript[p, 1 ]
     Cos[\[Tau]] + {{{Cos[\[Tau]]^4 Subscript[g, 4] \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(4\)] + 
       3 Cos[\[Tau]]^2 Subscript[g, 3] \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)] (-(1/2) Subscript[g, 2] \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
          1/6 Cos[2 \[Tau]] Subscript[g, 2] \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
          Cos[\[Tau]] Subscript[p, 2] + Sin[\[Tau]] Subscript[q, 2]) +
        Subscript[g, 2] (-(1/2) Subscript[g, 2] \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
          1/6 Cos[2 \[Tau]] Subscript[g, 2] \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
          Cos[\[Tau]] Subscript[p, 2] + 
          Sin[\[Tau]] Subscript[q, 2])^2 + 
       2 \[Epsilon]^4 Cos[\[Tau]] Subscript[g, 2] Subscript[p, 
        1] (Cos[\[Tau]] Subscript[p, 3] + 
          1/3 Subscript[p, 1] (1/8 Cos[3 \[Tau]] (-\[Lambda] + (4 \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(g\), \(2\), \(2\)])/3) \!
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)] + 
             Subscript[g, 
              2] ((-3 + Cos[2 \[Tau]]) Subscript[p, 2] + 
                Sin[2 \[Tau]] Subscript[q, 2])) + 
          Sin[\[Tau]] Subscript[q, 3])}}} == 
  0, \[Phi][\[Tau]], \[Tau]]
```